# How can I select a table skipping duplicated value postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this.

| id | grade_1 | grade_2 | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 20220304 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 20220301 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 20220228 |

I want to select the current row(in here, id=1) and a row where the grade's value is different with the row I selected.(in here, id=3)

Like This

| id | grade_1 | grade_2 | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 20220304 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 20220228 |

I tried to use subquery but it doesn't really worked for me. Is there any way to skip the duplicated value when selecting table?

Comment: have you tried ```SELECT DISTINCT```?

Comment: Rather `distinct on`.

Comment: either "DISTINCT" or "GROUP BY"

Comment: Do you want each distinct combination of grade_1/grade_2? The newest one, or lowest id?

Comment: For Grade 1/1 which record must we keep ? What is the rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it with group by and a max value to retieve the one you want

```
SELECT 
    grade_1, 
    grade_2, 
    Max(createdAt) 
from 
    yourTable
Group by 
    grade_1, 
    grade_2
```